# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array exception while lenght is multiple of 4

Tags: c#, encoding, windows-phone, base64

I'm getting `"Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string"` exception while trying to decode base64 encoding string. The problem is that I'm developing mobile application and to minimize memory usage application reading base64 encoded data line by line and immediately saves it to release memory. Now problem is that even if I check that my string's lenght is multiple of 4 and contains no invalid characters `Convert.FromBase64String()` throws an exception. But if I read all data and try to convert it with one piece - conversion goes successful. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Upd:
Oh dear, I found the problem - I've checked string for invalid characters, but I've forgot to check it for whitespace...
Thanks everyone.

Comment: There is no way around this unless you encode it in chunks as well. You're asking how to partially decode something that was encoded as a full blob. That's just not possible (in 95% of algorithms).

Comment: Base64 allows partial decoding by definition ... every 3 byte are encoded into 4 chars ... therefore you can decode every chuck of 4 chars as long as they match A-Z a-z 0-9 + / ... can you post your code and a sample input? ... an please note that an encoding like base64 has nothing to do with encryption

Comment: I've updated original question with sample string that causes exception.